# Is it possible to add a timeline using cartodb?

Tags: carto

I am trying to add a timeline in one of my visualization and I don't really know how to or even if you can add one in CartoDB. Does anyone know if you can and how?

Comment: It's possible, but can you describe what you're trying to do? This is a pretty good example: http://www.vizzuality.com/projects/rollingstones

Comment: am trying to make a timeline from crime, were crime will increase/decrease as the time changes if that's any clear.

Comment: but am trying to do this on CartoDB.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you can describe the data you have? Crime rates per region by year? And then explain how you want people to be able to interact with it.

Comment: my data is in different times during 3 day period. i just want a timeline were as the time changes during the day, different dots will pop up till the end of day 3 were all the dots on the map are visible, if that makes sense.

Comment: am new to CartoDB so i don't know what are the limits to it..

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [torque](https://github.com/CartoDB/torque).

If you're new to CartoDB, start by getting your static map onto a template. When you start trying to implement torque, you ought to be able to ask much more specific questions.

Comment: i made a static visualization with the data i have, but am trying to make the dots on the map appear as the time changes. for example something like this: http://www.theguardian.com/uk/interactive/2011/sep/05/england-riots-timeline-interactive?CMP=twt_gu

Comment: That's great. You asked if it is possible. The answer is "yes. with torque." If you want help implementing Torque, you should ask a much more specific question. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help writing questions that get good answers.